# AFNetworking POSTing malformed JSON - single quotes and [Object] refs

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I am using AFNetworking and I am trying to POST a JSON structure.  The problem is that instead of something like `{"my_property":"my value"}`, it's formatting it as `{my_property:'my_value'}`. I guess the loss of the first set of quotes is OK in most cases, but I'm not sure what to do with the non-JSON single quotes and am pretty confused as to why it would generate single quotes at all given that it knows it's creating JSON from an NSDictionary.  Additionally, it's including [Object] refs where I would just expect a "{".  This is what the server is getting:

```
...
num_matches: 32,
view_instance: properties_in_view: [Object],
[ { view_instance_ctr: 0, view_id: '4e5bb37258200ed9aa000011' },
...
```

The target is iOS 5.0, so I'm *assuming* it's using NSJSONSerialization to create JSON (although I haven't tried to verify this yet).  The dictionary I send validates to JSON with isValidJSONObject.  If I print out the serialized version, it looks great. The simplified version of the code looks like:

```
NSDictionary *params = myDictionaryThatValidatesToJSON;
httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient 
     requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:params];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation start];
```

I'm hoping there's a `bigDummy = NO` flag I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is on the server side - ie. the debug you've quoted in your question is not the raw JSON text received by the server, but some reinterpretation of this that some component on the server has done.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what is being received on the server but I'll double-check.  Note that I can successfully send the same JSON using a Firefox REST plug-in and indeed the logged data is all double-quoted.  One more note: I have previously successfully sent other data to other POST APIs on the server, but I had always initialized a dictionary with a big string I created that escaped double quotes.  I will try that now to see if it makes any difference and make sure it can't be a server issue.  Thx.

Comment: The other option is that if the JSON serializer is really generating [Object], then you must have an unusual object in your dictionary

Comment: I don't understand AFNetworking very well although it says it will use NSJSONSerialization if it's available.  If I do this:


    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:outDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSString *jsonOut = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

It generates valid JSON.  I am programmatically creating the JSON and  it's pretty straightforward so I don't think I'm introducing anything weird.

Comment: So, if I take my original dictionary, serialize it and then create a new dictionary from the serialized content, it works (goes to the server properly formatted).  I wonder if it's possible that AFNetworking isn't actually using NSJSONSerialization to serialize the output and is instead using a backup library (I have SBJSON in the project as well)?

Comment: Well I guess the first question is if you explicitly call SBJSON does it return the same strange string? You could also single step through AFNetworking with the debugger and see what it is actually calling.

Answer (score 0):

Michael is correct. By using his code of data i'm using this to perform POST request with JSOn parameter :

// dataDictionary is your parameter dictionary

```
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    //NSString *jsonOut = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webURL]];

    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"Webservice URL"
                                                      parameters:nil];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:jsonData];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // Print the response body in text

        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);


    }];
    [operation start];
```

Comment: You can also use `AFHTTPClient`'s `setParameterEncoding` instead of having to set some of those headers.